# Persistence unit error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, derby

I have made a project in OSX in Java with Netbeans and working on it with colleagues that work on windows with github.

Once they clone the project they get below error that signifies that it cannot connect to the derby Database with eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named MovieDatabasePU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at moviedatabase.MovieDatabase.deleteFromDB(MovieDatabase.java:126)
    at moviedatabase.MovieDatabase.main(MovieDatabase.java:48)
C:\Users\Mixalis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Homework3\Ergasia3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1076: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Mixalis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Homework3\Ergasia3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:830: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I have checked all the similar problems that are described on Stack, but the persistence.xml is correct and it is located on the META-INF folder which is located on the src/META-INF folder.

Below is the persistence file structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MovieDatabasePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>moviedatabase.entities.FavoriteList</class>
    <class>moviedatabase.entities.Genre</class>
    <class>moviedatabase.entities.Movie</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/person"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="pli24"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pli24"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[image]

From the debugging the error occur on below statement:

```
 private static void deleteFromDB() {
        EntityManager em;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MovieDatabasePU"); <-- This line

        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
```

What could else be wrong, because I have tried almost every solution and still no database connection.

Comment: Have your colleagues started the Derby Network Server on port `localhost:1527` prior to running the application? Your JDBC Connection URL says to connect to that server.

Comment: Yes, first they connect to database then they try to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I only had to do a clean and Build to make it work!!!
All files were ok and clean only wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your `persistence.xml` should be in the `/src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder, not in the `src/META-INF` one.

Comment: There is no src/main/resources folder. Once I create it and put META-INF folder in, but again the same problem!

Comment: eclipse is imported on Library. I have checked the structure with a newly created project on windows that works and the folder tree is the same!

Comment: Try adding these properties in your persistence unit:       <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>            
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>

Comment: the same error again. Somehow it doesn't see the persistence provider!

Comment: Take a look here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Derby and replicate the same example

Comment: I have done all those and still nothing. It's really awkward what is happening